# getUrl doesn't work as it puts the numbered array key in the url

Tags: magento

`<?php $daurl = Mage::getUrl('showdown/index/vote',array('c', 'd')) ?>`

Produces this result

> http://desbest.uk.to/clients/magentofull/index.php/showdown/index/**vote/0/c/1/d**

But I don't want it to be `vote/0/c/1/d`

Instead I want `vote/c/d`

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this instead :

```
<?php $daurl = Mage::getUrl('showdown/index/vote', array('c' => 'd')) ?>
```